# CRON expression for repeat every 2 or 3 weeks and on selected day of week

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to create cron expression for repeating on 2 or 3 weeks on seleted day like Sunday,Monday etc.

Is cron expression generation possible?
If not then any alternative to handle by java code?

Thanks

Comment: Any way ,whatever the link you provided is never giving the solution.

Comment: There are plenty of questions about how to schedule a Quartz job to repeat every X weeks on X particular day(s). I just picked the one with more upvotes. Surely you can search the site for "quartz weeks" by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using [CronTrigger class](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html). It uses a particular cron expression that you can use for your special need. For example the next expressions

```
0 0 10 ? * 2#2
0 0 10 ? * 2#3
```

will fire every second/third Monday of the month at 10 am.

Comment: No ,this wont help.User can select any number of days from week and even user can select any frequency like every 2 week or every 3 week.

Comment: You can setup programmatically the CronTrigger using a CronScheduleBuilder http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html